# Adobe premier CS6 could not find any capable video play module

Tags: video, graphics-card, adobe-premiere

I installed Adobe Premier CS6 into my PC but I'm getting following enclosed error:

[image: Adoble Premiere Pro Startup Error]

When I googled it I found the following solution that mentioned:

1. Include the Adobe premier.exe and GPUSniffer file into Switchable Graphic card application and turn it to "High Performance"
2. Run Adobe Premier CS6 in "Administrator mode".

That doesn't work for me, therefore I would like to know does any one has different thoughts what should I try?

FYI: MY PC performance is:

- HP Pavilion G6
- AMD Radeaon 1gb
- 4GB RAM
- Windows 7 64bit Ultimate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same laptop, but with a 7670M AMD graphic card.

If you haven't found the solution to this yet, this is what I did(and it worked):

1. Go to Device Manager from control panel.
2. Disable the AMD graphic card.
3. Run Premiere Pro from that config.
4. Enable AMD card again.

Premiere Pro runs perfectly fine after that.

Hope this helped.

Thanks.

Comment: You must be a wizard!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for that. 
It's because your firewall is blocking adobe premiere pro.exe file, GPUSniffer.exe, and dynamicklinkmanager.exe. 
You just have to let those files through your firewall.

That's all.

Comment: That's completely true. Make sure you don't block Adobe Premiere Pro and its processes, like GPUSniffer.exe and dynamicklinkmanager.exe with a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable the AMD graphics card.

   - Go to Device Manager
   - Go to the display adapter, right-click on the graphics card driver and disable it
2. Run Premiere Pro from that configuration.
3. Enable the AMD card again (repeating the same process from the first step, but enabling the graphics card)

Comment: Can you explain in detail how to do this? This isn't very useful as it stands.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) would be even better if you edit and expand it with an explanation as to *why* your solution fixes/addresses the OPs question.

Answer (score 0):

install Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013, x86 version, not only x64 version, I install every packages from 2008 to 2015, and at last soluted this problem.
安装 Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 ，注意要 x86 版

Comment: Because the GPUSniffer.exe is need this runtime package, and it's a x86 application.